# AutoMapper's 1.1 CreateMap raises NullReferenceException after long uptime

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm hosting an application which uses AutoMapper to convert certain classes to others. This was going fine until today. The application has been hosten for approximately 3 months now. In between we've done several deploys in which the application has been restarted, but IIS has not.

From out of nowhere the application started to fail, looking back at the logs we found out that this is the cause:

```
    System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at AutoMapper.Configuration.<>c__DisplayClass13.<FindExplicitlyDefinedTypeMap>b__12(TypeMap x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at AutoMapper.Configuration.FindExplicitlyDefinedTypeMap(Type sourceType, Type destinationType)
   at AutoMapper.Configuration.CreateTypeMap(Type source, Type destination, String profileName)
   at AutoMapper.Configuration.CreateMap[TSource,TDestination](String profileName)
   at AutoMapper.Configuration.CreateMap[TSource,TDestination]()
   at AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap[TSource,TDestination]()
```

So we switched to our backup server, which does not have this problem at all.
We tried to fix the problem by restarting the application, which did not help. Only restarting IIS fixed the issue.

We tried looking in the source to find out what is causing this issue, which we downloaded at https://github.com/jbogard/AutoMapper/. The exception seems to be caused in this method of the ConfigurationStore class of AutoMapper.

```
    private TypeMap FindExplicitlyDefinedTypeMap(Type sourceType, Type destinationType)
    {
        return _typeMaps.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DestinationType == destinationType && x.SourceType == sourceType);
    }
```

_typeMaps is defined as the following in the class.

```
    private readonly IList<TypeMap> _typeMaps = new List<TypeMap>();
```

If we check in the TypeMap we see that the x.DestionationType and x.SourceType reference to other properties:

```
    private readonly TypeInfo _destinationType;
    private readonly TypeInfo _sourceType;

    public Type SourceType
    {
        get { return _sourceType.Type; }
    }

    public Type DestinationType
    {
        get { return _destinationType.Type; }
    }
```

It looks like _sourceType and/or _destionationType are null al the sudden!

Has anyone else faced this issue and/or does anybody know a possible cause for this problem and how we can prevent this from happening in the future?

Answer (score 1):

If I may, Automapper will generally throw this exception when it has ben told to map something which is (as the error indicates) null.

For example, if we were to say:

```
MyCustomObject myobject = null;
MyNewObject mynewobject = Mapper.Map<MyCustomObject, MyNewObject>(myobject);
```

We would get the same error since we're telling Automapper to make a new `MyNewObject` out of a null `MyCustomObject`.

From the looks of your error message, the issue looks like an empty `List`.  Automapper is expected a bunch of objects it can map to something else, but the list is empty.

Automapper can be a bit of a pig to track down errors in, since the error will be thrown by Automapper and look like an Automapper issue.  Naturally the problem is that somewhere, somehow your code is throwing an empty list in for mapping.

Do you know if you have any unit tests you can examine?  If so, check the code coverage for them (something like [NCover](http://www.ncover.com/)) and make sure all your mapping code is being exercised.  If not, get some tests written to exercise it.

An alternative might be to try running the same operation on a development workstation and try to recreate the situation with the error - it might be a database table that's now empty, or some unspecified user input.

Do you have any logging enabled in your software, something like [Enterprise Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648951.aspx) logging, for example?

Good luck :)